# Python Dataframe

Tags: python, loops, dataframe

I am a Java programmer and I am learning python for Data Science and Analysis purposes.

I wish to clean the data in a Dataframe, but I am confused with the pandas logic and syntax.

What I wish to achieve is the something like the following Java code:

```
for( String name : names ) {
     if (name == "test") {
       name = "myValue";}
  }
```

How can do it with python and pandas dataframe.
I tried as following but it does not work

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('Dataset V02.csv')

array = df['Order Number'].unique()

#On average, one order how many items has?

for value in array:
    count = 0
    if df['Order Number'] == value:
        ......
```

I get error at df['Order Number']==value.
How can I identify the specific values and edit them?

In short, I want to:
-Check all the entries of 'Order Number' column
-Execute an action (example: replace the value, or count the value) each time the record is equal to a given value (example, the order code)

Comment: Sorry what are you trying to do here? Your initial snippet is just a value replacement, but in your long form you look like you're trying to count the unique values so which is it

Comment: python throws an error at the moment I try to identify a specific value (df['Order Number']==value), therefore I can't do anything after.

Comment: The normal form with any problem description is to include all relevant information, if you have an error it would be prudent to include the error in your question. Anyway, `if` doesn't know how to treat the boolean array that is returned from `df['Order Number'] == value:` it probably complains that you should use `all`, `any` etc... However, you failed to answer my question, what are you trying to achieve? What is the desired output/result

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited my question.
In short, I want to: -Check all the entries of 'Order Number' column
 -Execute an action (example: replace the value, or count the value) each time the record is equal to a given value (example, the order code)

Comment: For replacement do this: `df.loc[df['Order Number'] == 'test', 'Order Number'] = 'myValue' for the latter you can just do `df['Order Number'].value_counts()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the vectorised form for replacement:

```
df.loc[df['Order Number'] == 'test'
```

This will compare the entire column against a specific value, where this is `True` it will replace just those rows with the new value

For the second part `if` doesn't understand boolean arrays, it expects a scalar result. If you're just doing a unique value/frequency count then just do:

```
df['Order Number'].value_counts()
```

Answer (score 0):

The code goes this way

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("Dataset V02.csv")
array = df['Order Number'].unique()
for value in array:
      count = 0
      if value in df['Order Number']:
      .......
```

You need to use "in" to check the presence. Did I understand your problem correctly. If I did not, please comment, I will try to understand further.

Comment: This won't work `in` doesn't understand boolean array result so this is no different to what the OP tried

Comment: @EdChum Oh! Thank you! I learnt a new point, Please don't downvote my answer. I am running short of reputation.